# "Кажется" в данном случае вводное слово или сказуемое?

Tags: вводные-слова

```
Мать-земля родная наша,
В дни беды и в дни побед
Нет тебя светлей и краше
И желанней сердцу нет.
Помышляя о солдатской
Непредсказанной судьбе,
Даже лечь в могиле братской
Лучше, кажется, в тебе.
```

Тут подразумевается "мне кажется"?

Answer (score 1):

У Твардовского запятые стоят, значит, это всё-таки **вводное слово.**

Если по смыслу  посчитать **кажется** сказуемым, вызывает сомнение вид этого сказуемого, более подходило бы **казалось лучшим**.